# FILE Receive Location - How to define file mask with 2 extensions

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I would like to only get files ending with *.xls OR *.xlsx extension from my Receive Location.
How should "File mask" look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not personally tested that BizTalk only uses the first 3. charaters, but if so, this is probably a dangerous solution, since it might be addressed in future hotfixes.

I would suggest creating two receive locations, one for each filter, and bind them to the same receive port. This is also more future-proof since you can add any number of folders or file types. And that is basically the design idea behind ReceivePorts and -locations.

If you are using orchestrations, these are bound to the Receive Port anyway and you do not need to make any changes for this to work. If this is a messaging only scenario, you just need to make sure that your subscriptions/filters are not based on the name of the receive location and you are fine.

Comment: Thanks. I just changed that to your suggestion and it works nicely. Also it is much cleaner now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

File adapter uses three chars only for extension, so even if you give *.xlsx it will pick both *.xls and *.xlsx file. You don't need to do anything in yr case just use *.xlsx for file mask

Comment: This is indeed the way to go in this situation!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a single Receive Location:

> Only one file mask or file name can be specified per receive location or send port.

See MSDN: [Restrictions on the File Mask and File Name Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578688.aspx)

**However**, you can use the [File Adapter SDK Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578623.aspx) and build your own Adapter to use a regular expression as described in this [blogpost](http://martijnh.blogspot.nl/2004/06/file-adapter-with-regular-expressions.html).